# jquery ui slide trigger a page get

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am rather new to web programming. So this question is probably rather basic.

I have a **ASP.NET** page using MVC that can take a parameter and return a page that contains a slider. 
I would like the slider to trigger getting a new page where the parameter corresponds to the setting of the slider.

How do I write the callback in the slider to trigger this page refresh with the correct parameter?

The controller has the following signature:

```c#
public class TaskController : Controller
{
    private WebApplication7Entities db = new WebApplication7Entities();

    // GET: /Task/
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

The View (*cshtml*) has the following code:

```html
@model WebApplication7.Models.Revision_Range_Current_Revision_Tasks_of_this_Revision
....
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#slider").slider({ 
              min: @(Model.min_revision), 
              max: @(Model.max_revision), 
              value: @(Model.current_revision),
              slide: function(event, ui) { 
                 xxxx_get_page_task_with_parm(ui.value)}
                 });
             });
        })
    </script>

}
```

---

What I need is the snippet of code to replace `xxxx_get_page_task_with_parm(ui.value)`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({ min: @(Model.min_revision), max: @(Model.max_revision), value: @(Model.current_revision) 
                         , slide: function(event, ui) { window.location = '/Task/Index?id=' + ui.value}
                         });

})
```